# Cleaning up text from a URL as a CSV, then representing it as a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, urllib

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import urllib.request
import time

x = urllib.request.urlopen("https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?pairs=EURUSD,EURJPY,GBPUSD,USDCAD,GBPJPY,USDJPY,AUDUSD,&api_key=KEY")

df = pd.read_csv(x,header=None, sep=',', 
infer_datetime_format=True)

starttime=time.time()
while True:
print (df)
time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

I wrote this code with the intent of pulling data from the URL and place it within the Pandas Dataframe. Then, minute by minute, updating the information to the Dataframe from the URL with the index of time. Currently i'm able to pull the raw data to the dataFrame but when he information is being called by the timer I made, it repeats whats been called before and not updating. The data that i'm getting is also very convoluted and messy, so I have not been able to even index time to begin with.

If I could be pointed in the direction of where i can learn how to clean the information in the datframe and how to call the data thats updated when put to the dataframe, it would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the data from the site is in JSON format.
Also your action of pulling the data was outside the while loop, so you only pulled once but printed every minute.
 Try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
import time

while True:
   df = pd.read_json("https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?pairs=EURUSD,EURJPY,GBPUSD,USDCAD,GBPJPY,USDJPY,AUDUSD,&api_key=KEY")
   print (df)
   time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful. Ive also added the line        df = df.pivot_table(['price'], ['timestamp'], 'symbol')      this changes the columns to the symbol pairs and has the index or rows set at time. but now, when the next row is added, there is still the column names. Rather, i would like to have the appending row be under the subsequent row. Also, is there a simply way to, instead of the update happening every 60seconds, be exactly on the minute?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that looked like a real API key, which you should not share.

The code you shared does not request the URL repeatedly. Only the lines in the `while True` loop will repeatedly execute. In your code, these are the lines that make a request and establish a `DataFrame` from the response:

```
x = urllib.request.urlopen("https://forex.1forge.com/1.0.3/quotes?pairs=EURUSD,EURJPY,GBPUSD,USDCAD,GBPJPY,USDJPY,AUDUSD,&api_key=KEY")

df = pd.read_csv(x,header=None, sep=',', 
infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Edit: as regards your question about how to begin cleaning data, the `pandas` [official cheat sheet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf) is not bad in my opinion.